# В файл записываются левые данные c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

При записи в файл, помимо текста добавляются различные символы, хотя если вызывать функцию без переменной с текстом, то все хорошо.

В чем может быть проблема?

```
writedata(dir, "hello moto kek lol test lul mur meow"); - все хорошо
```

---

```
char* kik = getdata();
writedata(dir, kik); - все плохо
```

---

```
void writedata(char* file, char* data)
{
    ofstream fout(file, ios_base::binary); 
    fout << data; // запись строки в файл
    fout.close(); // закрываем файл
    return;
}
```

---

upd:

```
int sock;
int bytes_read;
struct sockaddr_in server;
WSADATA ws;

char server_reply[2048];
memset(&server_reply, 0, sizeof(server_reply));
const int WINSOCK_VERSION = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
WSAStartup(WINSOCK_VERSION, &ws);
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(6896);
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    return "connectfail";
}
send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
bytes_read = recv(sock, server_reply, sizeof(server_reply), 0);
return server_reply;
```

Comment: Если эта функция  getdata(); возвращает указатель на локальную переменную функции, то, действительно, все будет плохо. Другая причина проблемы может состоять в том, что строка не завершается нулем. Поэтому покажите функцию  getdata();

Answer (score 3):

Массив `server_reply` является локальной переменной функции `getdata`

```
char server_reply[2048];
```

При выходе из функции эта локальная переменная прекращает свое существование. Поэтому указатель на этот массив, возвращаемый из функции, является не действительным. В результате программа имеет неопределенное  поведение.

Вы могли бы по крайней мере объявить эту локальную переменную, как имеющую статическую память при условии, что функция используется в однопоточной среде, или как имеющую спецификатор `thread_local` в многопоточной среде. Например,

```
static char server_reply[2048];
```

Кроме того, чтобы рассматривать массив, как содержащий строку, следует в этом предложении считывать число байтов на единицу меньше, чем размер массива

```
bytes_read = recv(sock, server_reply, sizeof(server_reply) - 1, 0);
```

Лучше было бы написать функцию таким образом, что она получает буфер как аргумент, а возвращает число прочитанных байтов.

Answer (score 0):

> помимо текста добавляются различные символы

Это говорит о том, что ваш текст, скорее всего, не завершен нулевым символом, как того требует

```
fout << data; // запись строки в файл
```